# Customize JSessionID generated by JBoss

Tags: java, apache, jboss, mod-cluster

Can we customize the JSESSIONIDs that JBoss generates (adjust the generated value, append certain unique strings to it, etc.)?

TIA

Regards,
Chandu

Answer (score 0):

I dont get your problem. JSESSIONID is used to identify the user.

You should put your information in the session and not into the session id.

Comment: I've modified my question :)